# Selenium, Java- finding table by class (without ID)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have something like this:

```
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Access</th>
        <th>Grant</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="role in roles">
        <td>{{role.role_name}}</td>
        <td>{{role.role_description}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="role.allow_access" ng-change="updateAllow(role)" ng-disabled="!(role.grantor_allow_grant == 'Y' || haveAllAdminRoles)" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="role.allow_grant" ng-change="updateAllow(role)"  ng-disabled="!(role.grantor_allow_grant == 'Y' || haveAllAdminRoles)" ng-true-value="'Y'" ng-false-value="'N'"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How I can find this table using WebDriver or WebConnector ? I tried sth like this:

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.className("table"));
```

and it doesn't work, I received error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there a `frame` tag in the html?

Comment: No, I don't see it.

Comment: Please come back and accept the correct one answer of giving these answers which really helped you and would help to other in future...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be due to timing issue. You can use explicit wait to wait for the table to load or to be visible

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement table = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("table")));
// or
WebElement table = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("table")));
```

Answer (score 1):

May be when you are going to finding table, it could not be visible on the page due slow internet or other reason. To make sure table visible on the page try to find using `WebDriverWait` to wait until table visible as below :-

```
WebDriverwait wait = new WebDriverwait(driver, 10);
WebElement table = wait.until(Expectedconditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("table")));
```

Hope it helps..:)